# Is there a way to implement GCM (or CCS) with a server using c++?

Tags: android, c++, c, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on an App that I've made for both iOS and Android. On the iOS side, I use a constant TCP connection and JSON messages for the push notifications. I want to do the same thing for the android version, however I'm not sure if it's possible. I think using the Cloud Connection Server http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html is the way to go, however it only shows samples for Java and Python. Is it possible to use this in c++?

Comment: I can't think of anything you can do in Python that you can't do in C++. And a quick search turned this up: https://github.com/jalcine/libgoogle-cloud-messaging   (oh nm it looks like that project is totally empty)

Comment: it uses something called XMPP, would I need a library or something to use that in c++? I'm using visual studio right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose whatever programming language to desire to implement the server side. The question is whether you can find an easy to use XMPP C++ library for connecting to the Cloud Connection Server.

I assume it will be easier to find an HTTP C++ library for sending HTTP requests to the GCM HTTP Connection Server. If you are not planning to use the upstream functionality (device to cloud), you don't need to go though the trouble of implementing/using the XMPP protocol.

Comment: I've used [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for doing HTTP requests to GCM. It might be worth noting that I'd expect better performance from an always open XMPP connection than HTTP requests.